# What to do when an approved edit by mods is rolled back by OP?

Tags: discussion

I endeavor to edit posts for the usual grammar, spelling, and formatting issues. Having done web accessibility remediation, I will also edit posts to be more accessible to the visually impaired that make use of a screen reader.

On occasion, after a moderator has approved my edit, the OP will either roll back or re-edit the post back to the way they had it before. This is very discouraging.

What do I do in this situation?

Comment: Try leaving a comment as to what you edited and why. As long as the sense of the post has not been altered it should be fine.

Comment: I have been appreciating and approving a lot of your edits and I'm thankful for what you have been doing to the community.  Didn't realize that this includes accessibility edits, which is great !  I hope those roll backs are few in between and are not too discouraging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some edits only make a slight improvement, but if an edit which does make a substantial improvement is rolled back, you can flag the post for the moderators' attention. Reversing useful edits is disruptive behaviour, and the mods can take action, including possibly locking a post to prevent further edits. A user who repeatedly reverts helpful edits might be formally warned by the mods, or even possibly suspended if they do not change their behaviour.

Comment: I will keep this in mind. As Ken mentioned, I will try leaving a comment first and see the users response.

Comment: Counterpoint: What one user might find useful, another could reasonably disagree with. If the OP says an edit conflicts with the intent of their post, I'd be inclined to side with them.  This has actually happened to me once.  I wrote an answer to a question about X, explaining that X does not actually happen outside of some very specific cases.  Some troll took issue with that and, not content to post their own answer, edited mine to say that X *totally happens all the time* and there's no way to know when it can and can't happen.  I considered this straight-up vandalism.

Comment: And for whatever reason, he wasn't content to let the matter drop when I reverted it, starting a big edit war that eventually had to be shut down by mods telling him to knock it off.

Comment: @MasonWheeler That's not a counterpoint! Edits shouldn't be changing the content of posts. But Agarza's edits are pretty much always exemplary.